# MS Access Multiple values in parameters

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong, I have a table I am trying to run a query which asks the user if they have a specific district they are looking for....

so my columns are

```
name    district   etc
Jay       1
Tom       3
Mary      5
Tim       5
Mike      15
```

I am trying to be able to have a parameter [which district?:] 1,5 .. It would display

```
Jay      1
Mary     5
Tim      5
```

Code:

```
WHERE 
    [District] Like "*" & [What District(s)] 
    & "*" OR [What District(s)] Like "*" & [District] & "*"
```

but I am getting

```
Jay       1
Mary      5
Tim       5
Mike      15
```

I am trying to avoid getting the "15" record.

Comment: Give this a try--  WHERE [District] In [What District(s)]

Comment: Won’t return any response when I put a , into the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reversing the `LIKE` expressions and checking by comma positions for 1) comma after (`#,`) 2) comma before (`,#`), or 3) before and after (`,#,`) and then exact or no comma (`=`).

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE 
       [What District(s)] LIKE [District] & ',*'
    OR [What District(s)] LIKE '*,' & [District]  & ',*'
    OR [What District(s)] LIKE '*,' & [District] 
    OR [Employee ID] = [What District(s)]
```

Advise user not to include whitespaces between entries as a complexity error strangely raises.

Comment: This worked for me ! 

I’m testing it to make sure no issues but looks good to go. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with a list of numbers separated by a quote, you can use the `IN` operator, like:

```
""WHERE [District] IN ("" & [What District(s)] & "")""
```

This would generate a valid SQL expression like:

```
WHERE [District] IN (1,5)
```

Reference : [the `IN` operator in ms-access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/in-operator-d5a10cdc-cdb2-4854-be22-7abdeb5a3236)

Comment: This will not work if `[What District(s)]` is a parameter instead of concatenated variable.

Comment: @Parfait: probably not indeed. But since the OP is showing concatenated variables in the first place, this still looks like an acceptable solution...

Comment: Parameters can be concatenated inside string literals.